# How to get object at specific index in Persistent Set - Grails

Tags: grails, set

I have a persistent set of objects:

```
def applicantFiles = applicant.recommendationFiles
```

How do I get the object at the ith element from a persistent set? I tried to do

```
applicantFiles[1] and applicantFiles.getAt(1)
```

Neither of which work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sets can't be indexed, they are unordered. If you need to index a collection then [declare it as a list](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#sets,ListsAndMaps):

> To keep objects in the order which they were added and to be able to reference them by index like an array you can define your collection type as a List:

```
class Author {

    List books

    static hasMany = [books: Book]
}
```

with the understanding that the associated table needs a column to use as an index. Otherwise there's no way to preserve an ordering. You can use [indexColumn](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.x/ref/Database%20Mapping/indexColumn.html) to specify the column to use:

> By default when mapping an indexed collection such as a Map or List the index is stored in a column called association_name_idx which is an integer type in the case of lists and a String in the case of maps. You can alter how the index column is mapped using the indexColumn argument:

```
static mapping = {
    matrix indexColumn: [name: "the_matrix", type: Integer]
}
```

http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.x/ref/Database%20Mapping/indexColumn.html

If you don't declare the instance variable with a type then GORM defaults the type to Set.

Comment: I have it set up like this already

`code`static hasMany = [ careerFiles:ApplicantFile,
      scholarshipFiles:ApplicantFile,
      researchFiles:ApplicantFile,
      communityFiles:ApplicantFile,
      financialFiles:ApplicantFile,
      recommendationFiles:ApplicantFile,
      scholarships:Scholarship,
      completedScholarships:Scholarship]`code`

Comment: If I call .class on it is telling me it is a persistent set?

Comment: @connor: it's not about the hasMany, what type is the instance variable recommendationFiles declared as?

Comment: Ahh I didnt see that. I am not declaring it as anything, does that mean it defaults to a set?

Comment: @connor: yes, it defaults to a set.

Comment: Okay, I appreciate that piece of information. and thank you for your explanation.

Comment: Keep in mind. With this setup, hibernate will look for `book_idx` column in `Book` table to persist indices.

Comment: @dmahapatro: yes, I should probably add that.